# Prove that $L_p[0, 1]$ is strictly normed for $1 < p < \infty$

Tags: optimization, vector-spaces, solution-verification

I was having trouble with the following question from Luenberg's *Optimization by Vector Space Methods*:

> **2.10** A normed space is said to be *strictly normed* if $\|x + y\| = \|x\| + \|y\|$ implies that $y = \theta$ or $x = \alpha y$ for some $\alpha$ 
> a) Show that $L_p[0,1]$ is strictly normed for $1 < p < \infty$
> b) Show that $X$ if $X$ is strictly normed, the solution to 2.9 (below) is unique.

Problem 2.9 (attempted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3823235/proving-existence-of-coefficients-minimizing-y-a-1-x-1-a-2-x-2-ldots/3825413#3825413), any corrections/suggestions appreciated)  is:

> **2.9:** Let $X$ be a normed linear space and let $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$ be linearly independent vectors from $X$. For fixed $y\in X$, show that there are coefficients $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$ minimizing $\|y - a_1 x_1 - a_2 x_2 - \ldots - a_n x_n\|$

**Question 1**: *could you provide feedback, if any, on my solution to 2.9?*

Both 2.9 and 2.10 are introduced before we've learned Lebesgue integration or about measure or measurable functions, so there should be a solution to 2.10 that doesn't require this knowledge.

**Update 1**: The solution to problem 2.10a is available [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581257/when-does-equality-hold-in-the-minkowskis-inequality-fg-p-leq-f-p-g). I had a question about it which I've included as a comment to the first response, if anyone is able to answer it.

**Update 2**: I was able to find a solution to 2.10b [here](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/na/PartIIIat/b04.pdf), which I modified to fit the problem in the answer below.

Comment: Maybe this may of some [help](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80139/why-is-the-l-p-norm-strictly-convex-for-1p-infty)

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581257/when-does-equality-hold-in-the-minkowskis-inequality-fg-p-leq-f-p-g)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 2.10 A normed space is said to be strictly normed if $\|x + y\| = \|x\| + \|y\|$ implies that $y = \theta$ or $x = \alpha y$ for some $\alpha$.

> a) Show that $L_p[0,1]$ is strictly normed for $1 < p < \infty$

The solution is available [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/581305/734982).

> b) Show that if $X$ is strictly normed, the solution to 2.9 is unique.

[Here's](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/na/PartIIIat/b04.pdf) the best solution I've found:

Let $X$ be a strictly normed space;  $y$ an element of $X$; and $\mathcal{U}\subseteq X$ the subspace generated by $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n \in X$. The linear approximation from $\mathcal{U}$ to $y$ using coefficients $a = (a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n)$ is written as $u_a$. Suppose the best linear approximations of $y$ are $u_\beta$ and $u_\nu$ where $\beta \neq \nu$ and $\|y - u_\beta\| = \|y - u_\nu\| = \lambda > 0$.

If $y\in \mathcal{U}$ then $u_\beta = u_\nu = y$, and there would be exactly one linear combination of $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$ equal to $y$ and $\beta = \nu$. Since $\beta \neq \nu$, the vector $y\not\in \mathcal{U}$, meaning that neither $y - u_\mu$ nor $y - u_\beta$ equal $\theta$. Additionally, since $y\not\in \mathcal{U}$, there exists no $\alpha > 0$ such that $y  = \frac{1}{1-\alpha}u_\nu - \frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}u_\beta$ and so $y - u_\nu \neq \alpha(y - u_\beta)$ for any $\alpha$. Since $X$ is strictly normed, by the contrapositive of the definition, Minkowski's inequality is strict. So

\begin{align}
\Big\|y - \frac{1}{2}(u_\nu + u_\beta)\Big\| &= \Big\|\frac{1}{2}(y - u_\nu) + \frac{1}{2}(y - u_\beta))\Big\| \\
&< \Big\|\frac{1}{2}(y - u_\nu)\Big\| + \Big\|\frac{1}{2}(y - u_\beta)\Big\| \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\|y - u_\nu\| + \frac{1}{2}\|y - u_\beta\|  = \lambda
\end{align}
meaning that $u_{(\nu + \beta)/2}$ provides a better approximation of $y$ than $u_\beta$ or $u_\nu$, contradicting the assertion that those were the best approximations. So, $\beta = \nu$.